# Сохранение матрицы в текстовый файл

Tags: delphi, матрицы, stringgrid

(#-разделитель)
вместо матрицы (3,3) {2 3 4}{1 5 8}{5 8 3}
получаю это {2#3#4#1#5#8#5#8#3#} в один столбец
помогите, пожалуйста, исправить это

```
    procedure TForm1.Button11Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
     f: TextFile;
     i, j: integer;
    begin
     if SaveDialog1.Execute then
       Begin
     Assignfile(f,SaveDialog1.FileName);
     Rewrite(f);
     for i := 0 to Stringgrid3.colcount - 1 do
       for j := 0 to Stringgrid3.rowcount - 1 do
         writeln(F, Stringgrid3.cells[j,i], '#');
     closefile(f);
    end;
    end;
```

Comment: А почему бы не использовать TStrings/TStringList? Задать ему свойство LineBreak, добавить в него строки StringGrid.Rows[i] и сохранить с помощью SaveToFile.

Answer (score 0):

Циклы `rowcount` и `colcount` надо поменять местами. Цикл `colcount` обернуть в блок  `begin` `end`. Значения записывать процедурой `write`, она не вставляет переносы строк в отличие от `writeln`. После завершения цикла `colcount` писать пустую строку через процедуру `writeln`.